# Quill module load issue with react-typescript based project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-quill

I am using react-quil, quil-mentions in my project. Created a custom editor component. There is no build time error when using the editor component but got a runtime error

[image]

In stackbitz demo, there is no error, But exactly the same code I am using in my project.
Stackbitz URL: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-i9sbwa?file=Editor.tsx

Any idea why this module not loading?

Tried removing lock files, clearing node modules cache, re-installing node, But no luck.

Comment: Did you check versions ? Upgrading older version to newer versions gives the module error. Also you can see which module has no support via chrome debug. If you find the module hit me up here.